# Value in list changed after running through loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I´ve been cleaning some data recently and there is just one thing that struck me.
Simple example:

```
test_list1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]

for x in test_list1:
    for y in range(0, len(x)):
        x[y] = 0

print(test_list1)

-> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, if I try the following, I obtain a different result:

```
test_list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

for x in test_list2:
    x = 0

print(test_list2)

-> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It seems rather odd to me that in test_list1, I was able to change the values in its sub-lists without actually referring to test_list1.
Why did the values in test_list1 change just by running the loop if I didn´t explicitly stated that test_list1[0][0] = 0 and so on?
In test_list2, it was not possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this strange? In the first one, you're mutating the list, by in the second you just rebind the variable to a different object. Those are two different operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be simplified to this:

```
a = 0
b = a
b = 1
print(a, b) # >> 0 1

a = [0,0]
b = a
b[0] = 1
print(a, b) # >> [1, 0] [1, 0]
```

That is because when you do `b = a` with numbers, `b` is a copy of `a`, so you can edit them separately. But when you do this with a list, the two variables correspond to the same object. This is mostly done to improve efficiency (copying a list every time you do something like `a = b` would be very inefficient and often useless). So when you edit one, the other one is affected.

In `for x in test_list2:`, `x` is a copy of an element of `test_list2`. But in `for x in test_list1:`, `x` directly correspond to an element (a list) of `test_list2`.

For more details, you can read [this article about mutable objects](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747).

Answer (score 0):

I think the bottom line is that in your first loop, each instance of `x` is a list.  In your second loop, each instance of `x` is an integer.  In Python, lists are mutable, but ints are immutable. If you do a search online for "python mutable vs immutable", you can find a number of pages that describe what the difference is and why it leads to results like this.